# Nodejs - Mysql : "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" if Query Contains 'WHERE'

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

I have a question. Please, take a look at my script:

```
var dbconn = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '123',
    database : 'mydb'
});
var query   = dbconn.query("SELECT * FROM m02serials WHERE SerialNumber = '"+serialnumber+"'");
```

There is no error hints shown on my IDE for the above script. But, there is an error message just after the above line:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:137:25)
    at bound (domain.js:250:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:263:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:393:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:884:20)
```

**The above error message doesn't appear if I only write `SELECT * FROM m02serials` query (without `WHERE`)**. But, I want to put `WHERE` in the query. How is the right script to do this?

Comment: What is the value of `serialnumber`, does it contain any quotes?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The value of `serialnumber` is a string, and it doesn't have quotes. 
The error still appears although I change the query into a plain string like `SELECT * FROM m02serials WHERE SerialNumber = 'AA12QWE'`

Comment: Just in case, try to change the quotation mark from `'` to `"`

Comment: (you are going to have to escape it with `\"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the quotation marks from `'` to `"`.

Or you can change the [configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html) in SQL